# JScrollPane (Custom Scrollbar) in a PopEasy Modal Window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, scrollbar, jscrollpane

First time posting :-) I've looked everywhere for an answer and I can't seem to find it. I'm not a jQuery expert but do get my way around.

PopEasy: http://thomasgrauer.com/popeasy
JScrollPane: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html

I'm trying to get JSscrollPane to work inside of a PopEasy modal window. Terminology might be off, but I think I need to initilize it after the modal loads?

Here's the code for PopEasy modals: Basically you click an link and the modal shows:

```
$('.modalLink').modal({
    trigger: '.modalLink',
    olay:'div.overlay',
    modals:'div.modal',
    animationEffect: 'fadeIn',
    animationSpeed: 300,
    moveModalSpeed: 'slow',
    openOnLoad: false,
    docClose: true,
    closeByEscape: false,
    moveOnScroll: false,
    resizeWindow: true,
    close:'.close-button'
});
```

Normally, JScrollpane would just simply be:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

I'm assuming (and hoping) the answer is simple and I'm missing something small, but I've tried things that I don't completely understand yet like:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.modalLink',function($){
    $('.right-side').jScrollPane({});
});
```

I need help :-(

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jScrollPane is calculating the container upon init you would like to do the init/reinit after the modal is loaded, since PopEasy dosn't have a API for callbacks after the modal is loaded this is a little bit tricky.

The easy but poor way out is to add a timeout, like so:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.modalLink',function($){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.right-side').jScrollPane({});
    }, 500);
});
```

The alternative would be to add callback functionality to popeasy running the callback after the animation is complete.
If you need to reinitsialize you would need to access the jScrollPane API like so:

```
$(function() {
    var pane = $('.right-side');
    pane.jScrollPane({});
    var api = pane.data('jsp');

    jQuery(document).on('click','.modalLink',function($){
        setTimeout(function(){
            api.reinitialise();
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Adrian, thanks for the answer! It totally helped me out. I thought I left a comment before, but it got deleted or something? Anyway... I'm having a similar issue on the same site now... I have previous and next buttons connecting the modal windows that have the scroll. An example is on detroitdriven.org/leadership. Click on of the images to get the modal. In the top right you'll see arrows. I tried to do the same click function, but that didn't work... Any thoughts?

Comment: It is looking like it is the same problem, do you reinit the scroll after you click next/previous?

Comment: Shouldn't the same code snippet you sent work if the classes are the same?

Comment: I adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! Unfortunately that isn't working and doesn't initialize jScrollPane at all now. I reverted back to the first snippet you had. I actually met with my client today regarding a few other sites we are working on and she said the scrolling wasn't a huge issue and that we could get rid of the arrows. So... I might just do that... I'm still curious, but I don't want you to rack your brain on this. I appreciate you though.